# React Native Animation - Icon and App name

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, react-native-animatable

React Native: How do you animate the Image? i.e Image should Come from header and name should come from Bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [react-native-animatable](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-animatable)

```
export default function App() {
  return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    
    <Animatable.Text animation="slideInDown"  iterationCount={1} direction="alternate">Up and down you go</Animatable.Text>
    <Animatable.Image 
    animation="slideInUp" easing="ease-out" iterationCount={1}     source={require('/assets/snack-icon.png')}/>
  </View>
  );
}
```

I made a small [snack](https://snack.expo.dev/979eGg4wa)  Look there

Answer (score 1):

you should refer this:
[react-native-animatable](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-animatable)